# Python QuerySet object and or operator

Tags: python, django, list

I'm new to python and found some object lists while using djnago queries like

```
 querysetObj = <QuerySet [<class: obj1>, <class: obj2>]>
 queryset=<QuerySet [<class: obj1>, <class: obj3>,<class:obj4>]>
 for obj in querysetObj:
   queryset|=obj 
 queryset=<QuerySet [<class: obj1>, <class: obj3>,<class:obj4>,<class:obj2]>#it acts like a set compare objects and add none repeated objects only
```

I want to know how to do the same design with other objects "my own classes", is this related to operators overloading like c++ and if so , how to do this?

Comment: it does work , and I already tried check django

Comment: Querysets aren't lists, they're querysets. See for example the django ticket for where they were added to the [docs](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21333)

Comment: Yes, I want to do the same design but with normal classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by implementing the special `__or__` method (and possibly also `__ror__`), as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

```
class Foo:
    def __or__(self, other):
        return "Orred Foo"
    def __ror__(self, other):
        return "Rorred Foo"

Foo() | Foo()
# => 'Orred Foo'
Foo() | 7
# => 'Orred Foo'
7 | Foo()
# => 'Rorred Foo'
```

If the left operand has `__or__` defined, its `__or__` method is invoked. If it doesn't, or `__or__` threw `NotImplemented`, then the right operand's `__ror__` is invoked.

Other operators are implemented similarly, using the various special functions.

Comment: Thank you , I'm checking it with my own classes